# How to add text box data to database in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, winforms, tableadapter

I'm struggling to add text from a textbox to a new database row in Visual Basic.  I am using an SQL database in a .net windows form.

I have a binding source, and table adapter as well as the datagridview control with the database connected to the datagridview.

I am unsure if I need to declare the database in a separate private class of its own, or if I am just not using the right order of controls in my code lines. This may be very simple to most on here however I would greatly appreciate your expertise on this question.

Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MRX1DataSet2._Patient_list_' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Patient_list_TableAdapter.Fill(Me.MRX1DataSet2._Patient_list_)

  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
    DataGridView1 = Patient_list_TableAdapter.Insert(Last_Name_:=TextBoxLastName.Text)

  End Sub

  Private Sub BindingSource1_CurrentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingSource1.CurrentChanged

  End Sub
```

p.s This is just a simple one button, one text box, one form project that I'm using as a tester for the actual program.

Here are the errors:

> Error BC31409 sub 'Insert' must be declared 'Overloads' because
>   another 'Insert' is declared 'Overloads' or 'Overrides'.
>
> Error BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'toString' of
>   'Friend Sub Insert(toString As String)'.
>
> Error BC30272 'Last_Name_' is not a parameter of 'Friend Sub
>   Insert(toString As String)'.

Comment: If you are asking about VB, why have you tagged C# and C++?!

Comment: `The picture shows...` and then doesn't show a picture.  We don't want pictures of code.  Post code as text.

Comment: we'd love to help you but we can't see any of your code. Please copy and paste it into the question (and don't use a screenshot, code is not a picture, and we can't then copy it to use in an answer) and format it neatly [using the tools provided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson code update:

Comment: @ADyson                                                                      
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
                                                                         DataGridView1 = Patient_list_TableAdapter.Insert(Last_Name_:=TextBoxLastName.Text)

Comment: No, please edit the question to include it. Then it can be formatted nicely in a readable way, and it also forms a coherent part of the question so people can see it clearly. Press the "edit" button just under the blue "vb.net" tag to make changes to your question. Code snippets do not belong in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson sorry im such a mess, i edited the question so it can be available. if you can help me out and its successful ill cashapp you five dollars after taxes.

Comment: We're volunteers here, the only currency we trade in is reputation points. But thanks for the offer.

Comment: Now, you showed the code and explained what you wanted to do, but didn't identify an actual problem. Are you getting an error of some kind? Or some unexpected behaviour? Please clarify.

Comment: @ADyson my main goal is to connect the textboxlastname to the database by clicking buttonsave, however, doing things like: databasetableadaptermanager.patientlisttableadapter.insert(lastname.textboxlastname.text) creates an error on the insert function. same thing with the fill() function. im just not sure how to connect the textbox to add to the database through the button click event. the system wont compile correctly and the textbox data will not add to the database

Comment: What is the error then? You can't complain about an error but not tell us what it is!

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your patience, i edited the question and copied the errors listed in there. cashapp price upped to seven dollars for my stupidity and lack of clarity.

Comment: Which lines of the code does each error refer to? Please point it out in your list of errors. (don't use line numbers because we can't see those, just quote the code line as it appears in your sample above. If it doesn't appear in your sample above, then you need to show us more code). Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/insert-new-records-into-a-database?view=vs-2017#insert-new-records-by-using-tableadapters

Comment: i just wanted to say thank you to everyone who down-voted this post, i was able to find my solution by google searching. thank you for the encouragement and direction i have learned much more because of it.